# How to group inside "or" matching in a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have two kinds of documents to parse:

```
1545994641 INFO: ...
```

and

```
'{"deliveryDate":"1545994641","error"..."}'
```

I want to extract the timestamp `1545994641` from each of them.

So, I decided to write a regex to match both cases:

```
(\d{10}\s|\"\d{10}\")
```

In the 1st kind of document, it matches the timestamp and groups it, using the first expression in the "or" above (`\d{10}\s`):

```
>>> regex = re.compile("(\d{10}\s|\"\d{10}\")")
>>> msg="1545994641 INFO: ..."
>>> regex.search(msg).group(0)
'1545994641 '
```

(So far so good.)

However, in the 2nd kind, using the second expression in the "or" (`\"\d{10}\"`) it matches the timestamp and quotation marks, grouping them. But I just want the timestamp, not the `""`:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("(\d{10}\s|\"\d{10}\")")
>>> msg='{"deliveryDate":"1545994641","error"..."}'
>>> regex.search(msg).group(0)
'"1545994641"'
```

**What I tried:**

I decided to use a non-capturing group for the quotation marks:

```
(\d{10}\s|(?:\")\d{10}(?:\"))
```

but it doesn't work as the outer group catches them.

I also removed the outer group, but the result is the same.

**Unwanted ways to solve:**

- I can surpass this by creating a group for each expression in the or,
  but I just want it to output a single group (to abstract the code
  from the regex).
- I could also use a 2nd step of regex to capture the timestamp from
  the group that has the quotation marks, but again that would break
  the code abstraction.
- I could omit the `""` in the regex but *that would match a timestamp in the middle of the message* , as I want it to be objective to capture the timestamp as a value of a key or in the beginning of the document, followed by a space.

Is there a way I can match both cases above but, in the case it matches the second case, return only the timestamp? Or is it impossible?

**EDIT:**
As noticed by @Amit Bhardwaj, the first case also returns a space after the timestamp. It's another problem (I didn't figure out) with the same solution, probably!

Comment: In first case also it is getting the ```\s``` at the end of your 10 digits. What you need to do is to drop the ```\"``` search before and after from your regex to only look for the digits.

Comment: @AmitBhardwaj thanks for figuring out. Added just now as an edit of the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use lookarounds if your code can only access the whole match:

```
^\d{10}(?=\s)|(?<=")\d{10}(?=")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IEGw30/3).

In Python, declare it as

```
rx = r'^\d{10}(?=\s)|(?<=")\d{10}(?=")'
```

**Pattern details**

- `^\d{10}(?=\s)`:

  - `^` - string start
  - `\d{10}` - ten digits
  - `(?=\s)` - a positive lookahead that requires a whitespace char  immediately to the right of the current location
- `|` - or
- `(?<=")\d{10}(?=")`:

  - `(?<=")` - a `"` char
  - `\d{10}` - ten digits
  - `(?=")` - a positive lookahead that requires a double quotation mark  immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: It didn't work at first due to the ```\b``` in the beginning. Taking it out, it works! Thanks

Comment: @samthegolden It works, did you use it exactly as I showed? `rx = r'\b\d{10}(?=\s)|(?<=")\d{10}(?=")'`. It seems you did not use a raw string literal. If you take out ``\b``, you will get a `1545994641` match in `23436571545994641 INFO` (like [here](https://regex101.com/r/7LkW5z/1)).

Comment: maybe I didn't explain the best way. The document starts with the timestamp, though I didn't use a '^' in the regex

Comment: @samthegolden If there must be start of a string, use `rx = r'^\d{10}(?=\s)|(?<=")\d{10}(?=")'`. If you want to match start of a line, use `rx = r'(?m)^\d{10}(?=\s)|(?<=")\d{10}(?=")'`

Comment: yes @Wiktor, I used your first answer and added the '^'

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookarounds, but I think this solution is simpler, if you can just get the group:

```
"?(\d{10})(?:\"|\s)
```

**EDIT:**

Considering if there is a first " there must be a ", try this:

```
(^\d{10}\s|(?<=\")\d{10}(?=\"))
```

**EDIT 2:**

To also remove the trailing space in the end, use a lookahead too:

```
(^\d{10}(?=\s)|(?<=\")\d{10}(?=\"))
```

Comment: That would match the case ```"1234567890 blablabla```. If it has the first quotation mark it cannot have the space. And I think this way it would also neglect the second quotation mark, which should exist if the first exists.

Comment: @samthegolden Try my solution.

Comment: @samthegolden what about the one I added on the edit? Would it work for you?

Comment: @dquijada almost. Now it returns the space after the timestamp, as I added in the post as a new problem. But it solves my first problem actually!

Comment: @samthegolden added a third one solving that, even if you probably had figured it out already